# Removing left and right Double Quotation Mark

Tags: php

is there a way to replacing :

Left Double Quotation Mark  “
Right Double Quotation Mark ”
Left Single Quotation Mark  ‘
Right Single Quotation Mark     ’

the character saved exactly as “...” in the database (my database is using utf-8 unicode charset)

but when i fetch the data from the database it will return as a strange char â€œ and €
(im using Zend Framework, and using the fetch method of Zend Db Table to retrieve the data)

**How can i remove those chars from the string?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a utf-8 problem, don't try to solve it by manipulating the result strings with str_replace or trim, that would be removal of symptoms while the cause would still exist and potentially create more problems.

If it is a utf-8 problem it is important to know that not just the database collation matters but for example also the connection.

For Zend Framework you can use this:

```
//set connection to utf8
$db->query('SET NAMES "utf8"')->execute();
```

It's easiest to run this in your Bootstrap.php where you set up your database connection.

Answer (score 1):

this is not your problem, your problem about unicode, 
but for replace 
[TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) Function can help you!

```
UPDATE  my_table SET my_column = TRIM (BOTH '"' FROM my_colum);
UPDATE  my_table SET my_column = TRIM (BOTH '\'' FROM my_colum);
```

Comment: oh sorry, i read the first pharagraph only (:, i will edit answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to call a mysql query somewhere in controller.

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

I'm not sure this will help though. maybe they'll show up as needed.